# Merge geometry and empty raster

Tags: postgis, raster, union

I need to get 256x256 PNG-image filled with geometry (srid 4326)

For example, geometry which I want to draw:

```
ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((37.44140625 55.7745261452494,37.4434662 55.7756075,37.4463273787924 55.7765730186677),(37.4700392205152 55.7765730186677,37.4774551 55.7754144,37.494278 55.7709729,37.5162506 55.7688486,37.5389099 55.7657584))', 4326)
```

Empty 256x256 raster (upperleftx = 37.44140625, upperlefty = 55.77657301866769):

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeEmptyRaster(256, 256, 37.44140625, 55.77657301866769, 0.0001), 4326)
```

Final query:

```
select
encode
(
    st_aspng
    (
        st_asraster(
            ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((37.44140625 55.7745261452494,37.4434662 55.7756075,37.4463273787924 55.7765730186677),(37.4700392205152 55.7765730186677,37.4774551 55.7754144,37.494278 55.7709729,37.5162506 55.7688486,37.5389099 55.7657584))', 4326),
            ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeEmptyRaster(256, 256, 37.44140625, 55.77657301866769, 0.0001), 4326),
            '8BUI'
        )
    ),'base64'
)
```

What I want to get (256x256):

[image: (it should be png actually with alpha-channel)]

What I get for now (977x110?):

[image]

The question is: how can I create 256x256 png-image (with defined upper x/y) filled with geometry (or geometries)?

**UPD 21.07.2022**
If you want to reproduce query you need raster extension and GDAL to be enabled.

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_raster;
SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers = 'ENABLE_ALL';
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the same extent as the empty raster, you can find the union the empty raster with the original raster using `ST_MapAlgebra`:

```
SELECT
encode
(
    ST_AsPNG
    (
    ST_MapAlgebra(
      ST_AsRaster(
                ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((37.44140625 55.7745261452494,37.4434662 55.7756075,37.4463273787924 55.7765730186677),(37.4700392205152 55.7765730186677,37.4774551 55.7754144,37.494278 55.7709729,37.5162506 55.7688486,37.5389099 55.7657584))', 4326),
                ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeEmptyRaster(256, 256, 37.44140625, 55.77657301866769, 0.0001), 4326),
                '8BUI'
            ), 1, 
      ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeEmptyRaster(256, 256, 37.44140625, 55.77657301866769, 0.0001), 4326), 1
      , '[rast1] + [rast2]'
    )
  ),'base64'
);
```

Comment: @tinlux, I've tried your query at it gives ```iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAABtCAAAAABrBOCKAAAAAnRSTlMAAHaTzTgAAAAySURBVHic
7cExAQAAAMKg9U9tDQ+gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADg1tbQAB/7k1ZgAAAABJ
RU5ErkJggg==```
Which seems to be just an empty image.